# How do I reference the HomeController in a UnitTest?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am getting the following error with a UnitTest for VS 2013 `The type or namespace name 'HomeController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Admin.Web.API;
using Admin.Web.API.Controllers;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Admin.Web.API.Controllers.Tests
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class HomeControllerTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void IndexTest()
        {
            var controller = new HomeController();
            ActionResult _Result = controller.Login("jschultz0614@gmail.com", "********") as ActionResult;
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(_Result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
        }
    }
}
```

And it is puking on the controller line.

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess you're missing a using directive or an assembly reference, like the error message says. Without seeing more code, I don't think we can say any more than that. Please post your HomeController.

Comment: You probably just need to add a reference to your test project that points to the other C# project in your solution (the one containing HomeController).

Comment: my references are Admin.Web.API, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools..., System, System.web and System.Web.Mvc. The Admin.Web.API reference has a yellow triangle on it.

Comment: `HomeController` is still just a class.  Reference like any other class

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your Admin.Web.API reference.

Comment: Since I have never done UnitTesting before, and I am still rather "Green" What exactly do you mean "fix" Admin.Web.API? It runs fine and compiles with no errors. What am I over looking?

Comment: Figured it out, I had some assembly version conflicts

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the Homecontroller is in another VS Project within the same Solution.

You need to add a project reference / assembly reference for the WEB API Project to the Unit Test Project.

To add a project reference, right click the Unit Test Project name in Solution Explorer, then Select 'Add Reference...', Select the Web API check box in the 'Reference Manager' dialog if it is listed or browse to it's location.

Click Ok. I expect the problem should be gone.

Comment: Already did that and the reference has a yellow triangle on it.

Comment: Check the version of .NET Framework for both projects. Sometimes if one is higher than the other this might happen. To do this, you need to right click the project name in solution explorer then select 'Properties' Check the Application tab, check the Target Framework for both projects. Ensure they are the same version.